# UILabel not wrapping in UITableView until device rotate (iOS8)

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a **custom** MvxTableViewCell that is associated with an MvxStandardTableViewSource. That Source is then applied to a UITableView. The custom table cell is defined without any Storyboard or NIB. It is laid out in code and uses AutoLayout.

```
this.searchResultsTable = new UITableView();
this.searchResultsTable.AccessibilityIdentifier = "SearchView_SearchResultsTable";
this.searchResultsTable.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
this.searchResultsTable.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
this.searchResultsTable.EstimatedRowHeight = 44.0f;
this.searchResultsTable.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(CustomerItemCell), new NSString("CustomerItemCell"));
this.searchResultsTable.AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true;
this.searchResultsTable.TableFooterView = new UIView();

this.searchResultsTableDataSource = new MvxStandardTableViewSource(this.searchResultsTable, new NSString("CustomerItemCell"));
this.searchResultsTable.Source = this.searchResultsTableDataSource;
```

The MVxStandardTableViewSource is databound to a ViewModel property of type List

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SearchView, SearchViewModel>();
set.Bind(this.searchResultsTableDataSource).To(vm => vm.SearchResults);
set.Bind(this.searchBar).For(x => x.Text).To(vm => vm.CurrentSearchCriteria);
set.Apply();
```

This all works fine until an item in the data source causes some text wrapping in one of the UILabels and consequently a different height to the other cells.

The cell height is mostly correctly calculated but the UILabel within the
cell does not get redrawn until the device is rotated. I am using iOS AutoLayout to layout the various UIViews in the Cell.

Here are some examples of the large cell in my layout, see the 
person "THISISAPATIENTWITHA-" (note this is test data not real people's data)

[image: Initial display of cells]

**Initial display of cells**

[image: Same cells but device has been rotated]

**Same cells but device has been rotated**

[image: Same cells with device rotated back to original]

**Still the same cells with device rotated back to original**

How do I get the UILabel to redraw? We only need to support iOS8 and above.

I cannot see an event or method that gets called when the data binding has happened that would allow me to effectively tell the custom cell "You now have your subviews populated with bound data so redraw them"

The table has another issue too that is covered by this question, [Implementing cell reuse for varying height cells in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099568/implementing-cell-reuse-for-varying-height-cells-in-uitableview)

**Simple Repro on Github**

https://github.com/munkii/TableCellResizeIssue

Comment: The answer is going to depend if you're supporting iOS 8 only, or need to support iOS 8 and iOS 7 (or down to iOS 6).  UITableView.AutomaticDimension will only work on IOS8.  I have some code snippets that work for iOS 7 and 8, but it might be easier if I just publish it on GitHub

Comment: We are iOS8 only. I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I've forked your GitHub project and submitted a pull request.  But here's my updates to your project.

https://github.com/SharpMobileCode/TableCellResizeIssue

**First**, you're using FluentLayout for your constraints.  Nothing wrong with that actually, but that's some good info to tell others. :)

**Second**,  in order for `UITableView.AutomaticDimension` to work on TableView Cells, there must be enough autolayout constraints defined in order for the cell to calculate the height of the cell.  `UITableView.AutomaticDimension` depends on proper AutoLayout constraints.

Since you were using FluentLayout to abstract iOS AutoLayout constraints, this was not obvious as no warnings were present in the application output window.  Though FluentLayout was technically correct, it however wasn't enough for `UITableView.AutomaticDimension` to automatically calculate each cell height.

So what I did was added a few more constraints.  Look in `CustomerItemCell.CreateView()` in the pull request (or my github link).  You can see that I added additional constraints for all the bottom labels so that they add a Bottom Constraint to the ContentView (Just like you did with `this.bornLabel`).  This had to be applied to all the labels on the bottom of the cell.  This gives AutoLayout enough information to properly calculate the cell height.

**Third**, This almost works, but if you rotate to Landscape, you'll notice that the long name cells will be bigger and have extra padding.  To fix this, I created another class called AutoLayoutLabel that inherits from UILabel.  I overrode the `Bounds` property so that it changes the `PreferredMaxLayoutWidth` to the proper width when rotated to Landscape, and back to Portrait.  You then will need to use AutoLayoutLabel instead of UILabel.  You'll need this for all labels that need to wrap.  I'm not sure how to set `PreferredMaxLayoutWidth` to auto in code, but this is how to do it programmatically (which also works for iOS 7).

```
public class AutoLayoutLabel : UILabel
    {
        public override CGRect Bounds
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Bounds;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Bounds = value;
                if(this.Lines == 0 && Bounds.Size.Width != PreferredMaxLayoutWidth)
                {
                    PreferredMaxLayoutWidth = Bounds.Size.Width;
                    SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, that should do it!

Comment: I am not using a Storybaord/XIB it is all code based. I use tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(cellType, this._cellIdentifier) passing the Type of my Cell. I have seen a few posts talking about the Label's PreferredMaxLayoutWidth but have not been able to get any of them to work

Comment: I see.  It's hard to say without looking at code.  I think that your autolayout constraints have to be just right in order for it to work (i.e. it must have enough constraints to calculate the height).  What happens if you set your PreferredMaxLayoutWidth on your labels to 0?  If you can provide a working sample app that re-creates the issue, I can take a look at it.

Comment: did you see my answer?

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee, I just edited my answer with your input, and mine for the cell height.

Comment: I am just trying to implement your CalculateHeight but doing so fires loads of Constraint warning. The usual ones around NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint except that should not apply because I have set TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false AND it doesn't normally apply

Comment: Maybe it's best if you upload a small sample application that reproduces the issue.  Thoug this should work, as I have it working on my app, there maybe something else going on that I can't see in your app.

Comment: SharpMobileCode, I have uploaded a sample to https://github.com/munkii/TableCellResizeIssue. Happy to switch to your answer if you can get a me a final solution to this one

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee, I submitted pull request on your GitHub.  This issue was with your constraints.  AutoLayout did not have enough constraints to automatically determine the height of each individual cell.  In order for UITableView.AutomaticDimension to work properly, there must be enough constrains on your cell layout to determine the cell height.  There wasn't, so I added a few more and all is working now.

Comment: SharpMobileCode, Thanks.Your comment about FluentLayout suggests there is an issue with it too "Though FluentLayout was technically correct, it however wasn't enough for UITableView.AutomaticDimension to automatically calculate each cell height" Have I just misunderstood what you said? FluentLayout just creates NSLayoutConstraints, why would that not cause an AutoLayout warning? Or do you only get the insufficent constraint warning when using the xcode browser?

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee, You can still have NSLayoutConstraints that will work and not generate any warnings or errors.  At the same time, it still may not be enough information to calculate the height in the scenario where your UITableView is auto-calculating the height. So your constraints were correct and generated no errors, but needed a couple more added on the bottom to determine the height of each cell.  This article here is an excellent resource and explains it pretty well. Look under the "Pro Tip" section:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Answer (score 1):

I now have a solution to this part of my issue. Prompted by @SharpMobileCode reference to PreferredMaxLayoutWidth  I decided to give that another go. Rather that setting it to Automatic (which seems impossible in code) I am setting it Explicitly, once AutoLayout has done its thing. Like this

```
/// <summary>
/// Lays out subviews.
/// </summary>
public override void LayoutSubviews()
{
    base.LayoutSubviews();
    this.nameLabel.PreferredMaxLayoutWidth = this.nameLabel.Frame.Size.Width;
}
```

I am no longer seeing the Labels not wrap (hurrah!) however I am seeing an issue with what looks like cell reuse. Once I scroll all of the cell off the top of the screen I can scroll it back on and it has reverted to the same height as all the other cells. I can see the label is still wrapping but the cell height is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The standard table views in MvvmCross date back to iOS4 - while the new `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` sizing wasn't really added until much more recently (iOS8?)

Most real apps tend to use custom cells rather than the standard ones, but if you do want to use the standard ones, then I'd guess you could try adding some code to the setters in the cell which would trigger resize recalculations - e.g. to setters in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxStandardTableViewCell.cs#L73

I would **guess** that judiciously placed calls in there to request layout recalc would cause the parent cell and table to redraw.

Comment: The trouble is I am not using the StandardCell I am using a Custom one with AutoLayout and Databinding. There is no obvious place to insert the layout recalc call. Did I miss the "BindingValueUpdated" event :-)

Comment: Sorry - don't understand. Maybe try editing the question to add more detail or try asking a new question - it's hard to understand comment conversations sometimes (quite often).

Comment: Updated with more detail. I basically can not see how I can plugin a Redraw call when the data is bound to the UILabels

Comment: Now added screenshots too!