# Implementing cell reuse for varying height cells in UITableView (iOS8+)

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have a **custom** cell layout, inheriting from MvxTableViewCell. One of the cell's contained views is a UILabel that supports text wrapping. The wrapping will mean the cells can be of different heights as that is driven by how much text is in each data item. The custom table cell is defined without any Storyboard or NIB. It is laid out in code and uses AutoLayout.

I am finding that the cells are being reused and the heights are staying the same as they were when they were previously used.

When the data source is updated and new items are in the table the previously taller cells are reused for cells that don't need that extra height. Do I need to create a custom `MvxTableViewSource` that has specific reuse logic? How would I even ensure that extra height rows were not reused?

I am hoping this is not a Monotouch and MVVMCross specific issue but just in case, this is how I am using the UITableView

```
this.searchResultsTable = new UITableView();
this.searchResultsTable.AccessibilityIdentifier = "SearchView_SearchResultsTable";
this.searchResultsTable.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
this.searchResultsTable.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
this.searchResultsTable.EstimatedRowHeight = 44.0f;
this.searchResultsTable.AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true;
this.searchResultsTable.TableFooterView = new UIView();
```

The Table Cells display correctly on first use of the View but subsequent uses cause issues as does scrolling.

For example here is a screen shot of mixed height working followed by the same list after the taller row has been scrolled off the screen then back on. The red boxes show how box the cell should be (FWIW this is test data not real people's data)

[image: MixedHeight Working]
[image: Mixed Height After Scroll]

Another example, here the table is again displayed correctly then loaded again with the same data yet the second load has the cell height incorrect

[image: Working]
[image: Same data set yet cell heights wrong]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broke my two issues into two questions however there is a solution for both this one and the other issue with this SO answer, [UILabel not wrapping in UITableView until device rotate (iOS8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30243003/63286)